# Adding items to menu not working in multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom code that it will automatically add the category to the menu in multisite. Lets say I have a category name "Cat1" then once I run my code this will automatically added to the menu. However 1 issue is that it will added if the blog is loggedin. I want to be added if it is not logging in.

Here is my code:

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-includes/ms-functions.php');
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-includes/user.php');
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php' );


$_nav_menu_selected_id = wp_update_nav_menu_object( 0, array('menu-name' => "Primary Menu") );

$test = array( 
    array(
    'menu-item-db-id' => 0,
    'menu-item-object-id' => 2,
    'menu-item-object' => 'category',
    'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
    'menu-item-type' => 'taxonomy',
    'menu-item-title' => 'Rome',
    'menu-item-url' => 'http://sub.example.com/love/',
    'menu-item-target' => '',
    'menu-item-classes' => '', 
    'menu-item-xfn' => '',
    'menu-item-description' => ''
    )
);


if($item_ids = wp_save_nav_menu_items( $_nav_menu_selected_id, $test )) {

  foreach( $item_ids AS $single_item_id ) {

    $my_post = array (
     'ID' => $single_item_id,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_name' => $single_item_id
    );

    wp_update_post($my_post);

  }
}

    $menu_locations = array(
        'main-menu' => $_nav_menu_selected_id,
        'footer-menu' => $_nav_menu_selected_id
    );

set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $menu_locations );
```

If you run above example blog1.mysite.com it will added if I'm logging in on that blog. But if not they it will not added. However if I run it on www.mysite.com (not a subdomain) even if I'm not logging in it will added the category to the menu.